# Grizzly Graceful Shutdown throws InterruptedException

Tags: java, glassfish, grizzly

I'm working with a jersey server and want to be sure that when the server is terminated (usually via SIGTERM), all currently running requests are completed gracefully. If volume is high enough, there will likely be data loss if I don't do this.

So I'm trying to call [HttpServer](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/http/server/HttpServer.html).shutdown() from a runtime shutdown hook.

I think it is working correctly, except for one problem. [CompletionHandler](https://grizzly.java.net/docs/2.3/apidocs/org/glassfish/grizzly/CompletionHandler.html).failed() is invoked, with an InterruptedException. shutdownNow is in the stack trace, so it seems like there is just some logical error occurring after the shutdown itself has finished:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerGet(SafeFutureImpl.java:354)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.get(SafeFutureImpl.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:181)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerSet(SafeFutureImpl.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.result(SafeFutureImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.shutdownNow(HttpServer.java:458)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer$1.completed(HttpServer.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer$1.completed(HttpServer.java:376)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.notifyCompletionHandlers(SafeFutureImpl.java:199)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.done(SafeFutureImpl.java:287)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl$Sync.innerSet(SafeFutureImpl.java:383)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.impl.SafeFutureImpl.result(SafeFutureImpl.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener$1$1.completed(NetworkListener.java:698)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener$1$1.completed(NetworkListener.java:693)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.prepareForShutdown(HttpServerFilter.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener$1.shutdownRequested(NetworkListener.java:704)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.GracefulShutdownRunner.run(GracefulShutdownRunner.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I boiled it down to this test case which does not use jersey or a shutdown hook. It's very simple and the same exception occurs (in fact, the above is copied from the output of this program):

```
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer();
        server.start();
        try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        shutdown(server);
    }
    public static void shutdown (HttpServer server) {
        final boolean [] done = {false};
        server.shutdown().addCompletionHandler(new EmptyCompletionHandler<HttpServer>() {
            public void completed (HttpServer arg) {
                System.out.println("Shutdown completed");
                done[0] = true;
            }
            public void failed (Throwable error) {
                System.out.println("Shutdown failed");
                error.printStackTrace(System.out);
                done[0] = true;
            }
        });
        while (!done[0]) {
            try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }
}
```

Where's the bug?

Comment: working on it, https://java.net/jira/browse/GRIZZLY-1673